# Draft.js: How to clear editor content onClick?

Tags: reactjs, editor, draftjs

I've downloaded draft.js-utils, but I just can't find an easy way to clear the editor state of draft.js with useState.

At the moment I have the onClick function having the following, but it doesn't do anything:

```
 setEditorState(clearEditorContent.EditorState);
```

How to I use this correctly to return a blank EditorState?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The correct way is:

```
    setEditorState(clearEditorContent(editorState));
```